# How do I expand the apps on the launcher, like in windows?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

Designer/Artist here using Ubuntu for some neural network projects. I am pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux and I don't quite know how to get things looking the way I want.

The main thing annoying me is how if I have two Mozilla windows open they stack. I don't want them to stack. I want to see multiple mozilla things in my launcher, similar to the way that windows taskbar does. I'd also like if instead of just icons it could have an icon plus text.

I've seen things for Gnome to do this I think but I don't quite know how to get that working on Ubuntu? I'm on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: You mean 16.04, right?

Comment: Yes. 

Also the linked questions this are a duplicate of were very helpful. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Just wanted to add for any potential future question internet adventurers who find this page, I ended up going with Gnome Dash to Panel as my solution. It works great.